# Intermittent Internal Server Error on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, internal-server-error, access-log

I am at a bit of a loss. I am getting an intermittent internal server error. It is a WordPress site. I have already upped the `php memory` limit and replaced the `.htaccess`. I haven't updated or edited any plugins lately.

I need help tracking this down. I am looking at the access logs; But I am really not sure what I am looking for. Any help would be appreciated. This is a 1and1 managed server.

Comment: if you get a 500, your FIRST stop should be the server's error logs. Until you know WHAT caused the 500, anything else is just random flailing in the dark.

Comment: Ok. Well I am there now. What am I looking for is more important at this point then what my first stop should have been... any suggestions on that front?

Comment: get a date/time for one one of those intermittent failures, then look for that date/time in the log.

Comment: My issue was a WP plugin. Found the error in the server logs. `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Answer (score 2):

When debugging on WordPress, you don't need the access log. What you're looking for is the debug log. Every (almost) error will create an entry in the debug.log file.

Only, if you've enabled it. You need to add  to your wp-config.php file (or make sure they're on true):

```
 define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
 define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Note that you can find this log file under `wp-content/debug.log`

Then, you'll see what's behind this error in this log file. You'll find the error and the file with line which creates the error.

Comment: I am looking in the debug.log and the main reoccurign error is: `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php on line 6284` when I look in that file on that line `$title = $matchtitle[1];` the $title variable is being set. Any thoughts? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I actually fond a patch to that error. Working through some more.

Comment: It has been patched to version 4.7, the beta version is in the air. So you can already test it.

Comment: I figured it would be patched soon.